Expo splash screen support different splash screen image resolutions based on device size
I am working on an expo application which has the splash screen image configured inside app.json like below
{
"expo": {
     "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/resources/assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "cover"
        },
  }
}

Expo documentation gives that based on the device size, the size of the above image is reduced/increased and placed inside the splash screen when running the application.
Is there any way in expo where I can give qualifier images such as splash@2x.png and splash@3x.png so that expo runtime would pick the image based on the device size Like React-Native's Image do?
